# UFW Firewall Troubleshooting

Tags: apache2, firewall, ufw

!!!HELP!!!

Command I Need to run is as follows and returns the following error. Can anyone help troubleshoot?

sudo ufw show app list
Error: Invalid Syntax
Usage: ufw command

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0kcz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on WLS. I tried `ufw app list` without `show` and it worked.